# SQL Server 2008 R2 - How to split my varchar column string and get 3rd index string

Tags: sql-server

I have a record in a single column.Like below

```
Address
Arulraj   | Guindy   | Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 |  | 10000001 
Adaiakalm | Chenanai | Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 |  | 10000001
```

How to get the splitted string "TamilNaadu", "Chennai ","India " separately.

Comment: Please post a code snippet of what you have already tried and then point to the section where you are facing difficulty

Comment: your expected output is not clear

Comment: Usr3171957, you need to indicate how you are trying to use the separated values in order to get a decent answer. Otherwise people are just guessing. I think this is what @NoDisplayName was referring to regarding "expected output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will split a string inline....

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SPLIT] ( --SELECT DBO.FN_SPLIT('TEST1 , TEST2', 2, ',')
    @s varchar(512),
    @i int,
    @sep char(1) = ',')
RETURNS varchar(512)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret    VARCHAR(512);

    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT @Ret =
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END))
    FROM Pieces
    WHERE pn = @i

    RETURN @Ret;
END

USAGE : SELECT DBO.FN_SPLIT('Address Arulraj | Guindy| Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 | | 10000001 ', 3, '|')
```

RETURNS :  Chennai

Here's a table valued function that will return a table of values

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SPLIT_TBL](@InExp varchar(8000), @Sep varchar(10)) --SELECT * FROM DBO.[FN_SPLIT_TBL]('TEST1,TEST2', ',')
RETURNS @Res    TABLE(
    Pos         int,
    Value       varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @InExp)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @InExp, stop + 1)
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE stop > 0
    )

    INSERT INTO @Res
    SELECT pn, SUBSTRING(@InExp, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

    RETURN;
END

USAGE : SELECT *
FROM DBO.FN_SPLIT_TBL('Address Arulraj | Guindy| Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 | | 10000001 ', '|')
--WHERE Pos = 3 -- Uncomment this to only return index 3
```

RETURNS :

```
Pos Value
1   Address Arulraj 
2    Guindy
3    Chennai 
4    TamilNaadu 
5    India 
6    600042 
7    
8    10000001
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a function for this, long time ago, nothing fancy, but sufficient:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Nico Boey
-- Create date: 
-- Description: Returns the n'th part of a given string, split by a given separator, with n being a zero based index
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSplitStringPart] 
(
    @StringToSplit nvarchar(255)
    , @Separator nvarchar(10)
    , @Index int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE 
        @Result nvarchar(255)
        , @SepPos int
        , @PrevSepPos int
        , @currentIndex int
    if @Separator is null
        select @Result = @StringToSplit
    else if @StringToSplit is not null and @Index > -1
    begin
        -- init
        select @currentIndex = 0, @PrevSepPos = 0
        -- read ahead
        select @SepPos = charindex(@Separator , @StringToSplit)
        if @SepPos = 0 select @SepPos = len(@StringToSplit) + 1
        -- loop until index is reached
        while @currentIndex <= @Index
        begin
            if @currentIndex = @Index 
            begin
                select @Result = substring(@StringToSplit, @PrevSepPos+1, @SepPos-@PrevSepPos-1)
            end
            select @currentIndex = @currentIndex + 1
            select @PrevSepPos = @SepPos
            if @PrevSepPos = len(@StringToSplit) + 1 break;
            select @SepPos = charindex(@Separator , @StringToSplit, @PrevSepPos + 1)
            if @SepPos = 0 select @SepPos = len(@StringToSplit) + 1
        end
    end
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: While it is appreciated that you are trying to help, this is probably the worst way to split a string in SQL Server. The fastest way is a SQLCLR function. Other than that, there is an inline tally table or even an XML method. Please switch to using one of those; you will be happy that you did :).

Comment: As I said, nothing fancy. Was that not clear? You think I don't know sqlclr is faster, that there is a tally or xml way? Hm? By the way, where is your answer then? You prefer to comment in a pedantic way, rather than to provide an anwser yourself? Why don't you do something useful for a change.

Comment: Nico, I am sorry if I upset you by requesting that you not post known bad code for others to replicate. If you know of the other options, then why stick to this proven bad method? This has nothing to do with fancy, especially when some other better methods are less code. And I don't need to provide an answer to be helpful, as I am trying to be here. And in fact, if I have steered anyone away from this method and to a better option, then I have been more helpful than you (sadly). But this isn't really an answer either as it doesn't show the O.P. how to use it to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using `Sql Server 2012+`

```
DECLARE @str   VARCHAR(1000)='Adaiakalm | Chenanai | Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 |  | 10000001',
        @sql   NVARCHAR(max),
        @index INT=3

SET @str = '''' + Replace(@str, '|', ''',''') + ''''
SET @sql= 'select choose('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @index) + ', ' + @str + ')'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    DECLARE @str   VARCHAR(1000)='Adaiakalm | Chenanai | Chennai | TamilNaadu | India | 600042 |  | 10000001',
        @part2 INT , @part3 INT , @part4 INT , @part5 INT ,@part6   INT = 1
set @part3 = CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str)+1)
set @part4 = CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str)+1)+1)
set @part5 = CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str)+1)+1)+1)
set @part6 = CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str,CHARINDEX('|',@str)+1)+1)+1)+1)
select SUBSTRING(@str,@part3+1,@part4 - @part3-1) As "Part-3",SUBSTRING(@str,@part4+1,@part5 - @part4-1) As "Part-4",SUBSTRING(@str,@part5+1,@part6 - @part5-1) As "Part-5"
```